# jQuery Animation Callback

Tags: jquery, animation

ill be brief.

I found a piece of code and have changed it up quite a bit and it kinda seems to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('dota').click(function(){

     });

        $('#Homebutton').toggle(function(){
            $('.animateme').html('<img src="Construct2/Images/Gnoll_Running.gif" />');         
            $('.animateme').animate({
                left: '+=150',
            }, 800, function() {
                $('.animateme').html('<img src="Construct2/Images/Gnoll_Hit.gif" />');
            });
            $('.animateme').animate({
                left: '+=0',
            }, 500);
            $('#Homebutton').html('<img src="Construct2/Images/buttonred.png" />');
            $('.animateme').animate({
                left: '+=0',
            }, 500, function() {
                $('.animateme') .html('<img src="Construct2/Images/Gnoll_Resting_smaller.gif" />');
                });


        }, function(){
            $('.animateme').html('<img src="Construct2/Images/Gnoll_Running_left.gif" />');  
            $('.animateme').animate({
                left: '-=500',
            }, 2200, function() {
                $('.animateme').html('<img src="Construct2/Images/Gnoll_Resting_smaller.gif" />');  
            });
        });

        $('#AddOnbutton').toggle(function(){
            $('.animateme').html('<img src="Construct2/Images/Gnoll_Running.gif" />');         
            $('.animateme').animate({
                left: '+=250',
            }, 1000, function() {
                $('.animateme').html('<img src="Construct2/Images/Gnoll_Hit.gif" />')
            });
            $('.animateme').animate({
                left: '+=0',
            }, 1000, function() {
                $('.animateme') .html('<img src="Construct2/Images/Gnoll_Resting_smaller.gif" />');
                });


        }, function(){
            $('.animateme').html('<img src="Construct2/Images/Gnoll_Running_left.gif" />');  
            $('.animateme').animate({
                left: '-=500',
            }, 2200, function() {
                $('.animateme').html('<img src="Construct2/Images/Gnoll_Resting_smaller.gif" />');  
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

The problem is that I want the **"#Homebutton"** to change to red about halfway through the Gnoll_Hit animation.  So I spliced the Hit animation but that didnt do it.

I think I gotta do this with Callbacks because after the last animation is finished I want it to go to the buttons link.

Comment: yeah, i really think you are looking for a "flow control library" that is better than jQuery's. You can accomplish this goal with animate() and setTimeout(), but ultimately this style of animation requires a more thorough timeline than jquery provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, call it after the animate has finished, so add a function on the 2nd param and do the next set of animations there.

and some tip: you should try to use **jquery chaining**

```
$('.animateme')
    .html('')
    .animate( blah blah  );
```

so the code is a bit easier to read and bit faster.

then you can also use the $(this) inside the animate function

```
.animate( blah blah , function (){
    $(this).animate('');
  });
```

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use jQuery's delay() on the #Homebutton-change-to-red sub-animation, or you can "animate" a dummy variable from 0 to 1, and use a stepping function to get fancy with the behavior each time the function runs (which will be once per step of the animation).